# Sql lead ,lag, first value, last value ,rows between unbounded proceeding and window clauses in plain Scala (WITH NO SPARK)

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert SQL to scala just for my own knowledge I am able to solve several problems sum, count, min, max, group by, join and order by.

I want to know the answers to several other problems based on my example data which is below, lead, lag, first value, last value, and window clauses.

```
package SqlConversion_to_Java_Scala

import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.util._

object Example6SqlToScalaWindow {

  case class Employee(  var empid: Int,
                        var name: String,
                        var age: Int,
                        var dept: String,var salary:Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

   /*
    select
        dept,
        sum(salary) over (partition by age order by age des) as sum_over_age,
        max(salary) over (partition by age order by age des) as max_over_age
    from table
    */

    // create the employee list
    val empData: List[Employee] = new ArrayList[Employee]()

    // of the list interface
    empData.add(new Employee(1, "Ajay", 25, "Technical", 35000))
    empData.add(new Employee(3, "Chandan", 22, "Technical", 30000))
    empData.add(new Employee(4, "Arjun", 30, "Management", 54000))
    empData.add(new Employee(2, "Arun", 28, "Sales", 9000))
    empData.add(new Employee(8, "Anmol", 28, "Sales", 15000))
    empData.add(new Employee(9, "Vivek", 20, "Management", 8000))
    empData.add(new Employee(10, "Nikhil", 20, "Sales", 7000))
    empData.add(new Employee(5, "Rahul", 30, "Management", 60000))
    empData.add(new Employee(6, "Ganesh", 32, "Sales", 35000))
    empData.add(new Employee(7, "Vishal", 32, "Technical", 40000))
    empData.add(new Employee(11, "Anmol", 25, "Sales", 15000))
    empData.add(new Employee(12, "Vivek", 25, "Management", 8000))
    empData.add(new Employee(13, "Nikhil", 30, "Technical", 7000))

    val empSum = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.salary))
      .groupBy(data => (data._1))
      .mapValues(_.map(_._2).sum).toMap

    val empCount = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.salary))
      .groupBy(data => (data._1))
      .mapValues(_.length).toMap

    val empMax = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.salary))
      .groupBy(data => (data._1))
      .mapValues(_.map(_._2).max).toMap

    val empMin = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.salary))
      .groupBy(data => (data._1))
      .mapValues(_.map(_._2).min).toMap

    val empDeptName = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.dept)).toMap

    val sumPartitionByDeptAge = empData
      .map(rows => (rows.dept,rows.age,rows.salary))
      .groupBy(data => (data._1,data._2))
      .mapValues(_.map(_._3).sum).toMap


    empData.sortBy(data => (data.dept,data.age))
      .map(rows => (
        rows.empid,
        rows.name,
        rows.age,
        rows.salary,
        empDeptName.getOrElse(rows.dept,0),
        empMax.getOrElse(rows.dept,0),
        empMin.getOrElse(rows.dept,0),
        empSum.getOrElse(rows.dept,0),
        sumPartitionByDeptAge.getOrElse((rows.dept,rows.age),0)
      )
      )
      .foreach(println)

  }

}
```

Thanks
Sri

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems did you come across?

Answer (score 0):

Here is cleaner version of the code.

I have added methods for `first` and `last` because they are just the standard `head` and `last` operators.

The others (`lead`, `lag`, `window`) can be implemented using `sliding(2)` or `sliding(window)` on the `List` and then processing the appropriate element each time (with care needed at the "corner" cases at each end of the list).

```
case class Employee(
  empid: Int,
  name: String,
  age: Int,
  dept: String,
  salary: Int,
)

// create the employee list
val empData = List(
  Employee(1, "Ajay", 25, "Technical", 35000),
  Employee(3, "Chandan", 22, "Technical", 30000),
  Employee(4, "Arjun", 30, "Management", 54000),
  Employee(2, "Arun", 28, "Sales", 9000),
  Employee(8, "Anmol", 28, "Sales", 15000),
  Employee(9, "Vivek", 20, "Management", 8000),
  Employee(10, "Nikhil", 20, "Sales", 7000),
  Employee(5, "Rahul", 30, "Management", 60000),
  Employee(6, "Ganesh", 32, "Sales", 35000),
  Employee(7, "Vishal", 32, "Technical", 40000),
  Employee(11, "Anmol", 25, "Sales", 15000),
  Employee(12, "Vivek", 25, "Management", 8000),
  Employee(13, "Nikhil", 30, "Technical", 7000),
)

val byDept: Map[String, List[Employee]] =
  empData.groupBy(_.dept)

val byDeptAge: Map[(String, Int), List[Employee]] =
  empData.groupBy(row => (row.dept, row.age))

val empSum: Map[String, Int] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.map(_.salary).sum }

val empCount: Map[String, Int] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.length }

val empMax: Map[String, Int] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.map(_.salary).max }

val empMin: Map[String, Int] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.map(_.salary).min }

val empDeptName: Map[String, String] =
  empData.map(row => (row.dept, row.dept)).toMap

val sumPartitionByDeptAge: Map[(String, Int), Int] =
  byDeptAge.map { case (deptAge, rows) => deptAge -> rows.map(_.salary).sum }

val empDeptFirst: Map[String, Employee] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.head }

val empDeptLast: Map[String, Employee] =
  byDept.map { case (dept, rows) => dept -> rows.last }


empData.sortBy(data => (data.dept, data.age))
  .map(rows => (
    rows.empid,
    rows.name,
    rows.age,
    rows.salary,
    empDeptName.getOrElse(rows.dept, 0),
    empMax.getOrElse(rows.dept, 0),
    empMin.getOrElse(rows.dept, 0),
    empSum.getOrElse(rows.dept, 0),
    sumPartitionByDeptAge.getOrElse((rows.dept, rows.age), 0)
  )
  )
  .foreach(println)
```

Comment: rewrote code looks super beautiful to thank you, I just got the same idea this morning for first and last value, for lead and lag I am thinking of giving a row number (zip with index) and then do current row - 1 for lead and current row + 1 for lag and go a join on dept and age for example what you think ?

Comment: `zipWithIndex` will work but indexing into a `List` is very slow, so you would need to move to something like `Vector`. It is better to see if you can make `sliding` work for you. Have a go with `sliding` and then post another question if you can't quite get it to work.

Comment: if I post another question for sliding do you have an answer for it? I mean are you going to answer ? or you are just recommending me for its better to post another question to get an answer?

Comment: posted a different question for sliding ..., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785695/sql-rows-between-unbounded-proceeding-and-current-row-and-unbounded-following-l

Comment: I have seen the new question but it is really not clear what it is that you want to know. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to ask a good question. You need to be more specific and remove unnecessary information.

Comment: hoe about now I made few changes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785695/sql-rows-between-unbounded-proceeding-and-current-row-and-unbounded-following-l